# Finding minimum of $x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p$ subject to $x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I want to find minimum of $f=x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p$ ($p>1$) subject to $g=x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$.

By Lagrange's multiplier, if it has a local extremum at $P$, it should satisfy $\nabla f(P)=\lambda \nabla g(P)$. I solved it and got $x_1=\cdots =x_n=1/n$. So $P=(1/n,\cdots,1/n)$ is a candidate for a minimum. But I don't know how to prove that $f$ has actually minimum at $P$. How can I show it?

Answer (score 3):

A simple method is to use the power mean inequality:

$$\sqrt[p]{\frac{x_1^p + \dots + x_n^p}{n}} \ge \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} = \frac{1}{n},$$

with equality if and only if $x_1 = \dots = x_n$. This implies that the minimum is $n^{1-p}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> 'Close' to the extreme value you'll have:

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}x_{i}^{p}}\sim n^{1 - p}\ +\
\overbrace{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}p\pars{1 \over n}^{p - 1}\pars{x_{i} - {1 \over n}}}
^{\ds{=\ \dsc{0}}}\ +\
\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}\half\,p\pars{p- 1}\pars{1 \over n}^{p - 2}
\pars{x_{i} - {1 \over n}}^{2}
\\[5mm]&=n^{1 - p}
+\half\,p\pars{p- 1}n^{2 - p}\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}
\pars{x_{i} - {1 \over n}}^{2}\ \color{#66f}{\large > n^{1 - p}}
\quad\mbox{when}\quad\color{#66f}{\large%
p < 0\phantom{A}\color{#000}{\small\mbox{or}}\phantom{A} p > 1}
\end{align}

> You got a minimum !!!.

Answer (score 0):

From a strict convexity of $x^{p}
 $ for $p>1$

Answer (score 0):

As $f(x) = x^p $ is convex (for $p > 1$). We can use Jensen's inequality

$$ \frac{x_1^p+x^2_p+\cdots+x_n^p}{n} \geq \left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)^p$$

and hence it shows that the critical point you obtained using Lagrange multipliers is a minimum.